# Bitly API: batch handling clicks endpoint

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, batch-processing, bit.ly

I am using the Bitly API to track clicks of Bitly links posted on my network. At the moment I have to track them one by one. [In the bitly docs](https://dev.bitly.com/best_practices.html) I have read that the best practice is one of making a batch call to the `/clicks` endpoint. [However in the specific docs about the clicks endpoint](https://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks), nothing is mentioned about batch processing.

> Batch Processing The Bitly API does not support shortening more than
>   one long URL with a single API call. However, up to 15 URLs can be
>   handled in one API call using the /v3/lookup, /v3/expand and
>   /v3/clicks endpoints.

Nowhere in the Bitly documentation I can find any example to use batch processing. I did some tries myself, but none worked.

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&format=json&link=http%3A//vrt.nu/kijkuniversiteitvanvlaanderen&link=https%3A%2F%2Fbuff.ly%2F2AooMAX

https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&format=json&link=http%3A//vrt.nu/kijkuniversiteitvanvlaanderen,link=https%3A%2F%2Fbuff.ly%2F2AooMAX
```

I hope you can help me find the solution.

Thank you and best regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best practices in bitly.com states `/v3/clicks` instead of `/v3/link/clicks`. I guess `/v3/link/clicks` does not support batch process.

I tried links, link[], duplicate link in `/v3/link/clicks`. All do not work.

While `/v3/clicks` supports duplicate `shortUrl`.
[image]

WARNING: `/v3/clicks` in deprecated list, it will be deprecated but the official website does not state when it will be deprecated.

Hope it help.

reference: https://dev.bitly.com/best_practices.html

reference: https://dev.bitly.com/deprecated.html#v3_clicks